# how to clone the blocks while drag and drop using vue js?

Tags: drag-and-drop, vue.js

I am new to **Vue.js**. I am using Vue js to make Todo list. Here I am using **drag and drop** concept to move the blocks from one div to another div. the problem is I don't know how to clone the blocks in the parent element. Here is the code https://codepen.io/supraniti/pen/zogjGW?editors=1010.

And also to clone, 'LMDD' is using `lmdd-clonner` and `lmdd-dispatcher` classes to clone the draggable blocks. And this is the link referring to the details of cloning. https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/

Anyone help me how to clone the blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clone, just copy the element from the original array instead of removing it:

```
    newContainer.splice(newIndex, 0, oldContainer[oldIndex]);
```